# SQLite setup Error

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

I try to load Sqlite Bundle to my computer from this link: http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.107.0/sqlite-netFx20-setup-bundle-x64-2005-1.0.107.0.exe

But its show this error. In my PC already loaded ".Net Framework 4.6" but its says v2.0 or higher is required.

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to download the correct SQLite version for your .NET environment. [This one](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.107.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.107.0.exe) should be the correct one for .NET 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you do not in fact have the right framework installed, I would recommend you re-install it and ensure that you get the latest version.

If you just uninstall you can get the latest version from this link: 
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime

Comment: It's the opposite, need to download an updated version of SQLite from the website